# QRcode по ссылке

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, webforms, qrcode

Задача следующая, нужно что бы перейдя по ссылке сразу получить изображение QR кода согласно get параметров в URL. Как например [тут](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world). В связи с политикой информационной безопасности нет возможности использовать сторонний сервис по генерации QR кодов. Локальное приложение создал на C# webforms, если перейти по ссылке `http://localhost/Main.aspx?QRcode=12354654` в папку img упадет .png файл с QR кодом следующего значения:12354654. Мне необходимо что бы вовремя перехода сразу открывало изображения как в примере с гугл апи без дополнительного рефреша. Получается, необходимо выполнить создание изображение с QR кодом до метода `Page_Load` и в `Page_Load` загрузить уже изображение. Прошу подсказать, что делать?

Comment: Можно и в Page_Load это делать. Сперва создаётся картинка, после чего пытаемся её открыть. Если у программы выходит - показываем, если нет, просим её ещё раз выполнить операцию. И так до тех пор, пока изображение не откроется или время запроса не будет превышено. Можно ещё после создания операции по созданию картинки поставить таймер на пару секунд, а после открывать изображение с проверкой на успешность открытия.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev плиз дайте пример, как именно открыть ее после того как она была создана без рефреша

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы ASP.NET-страницей вернуть файл, нужно очистить Responce и записать туда файл:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 /*сгенерировать MyImage.png*/
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "image/png";
 Response.TransmitFile("MyImage.png");
 Response.End();
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136034/8674428